# Achieve Default model Binding working with custom model binder in WebPI and asp.net mVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, imodelbinder

I created a `custom Model binder` working fine with all the properties.
But the issue is I am missing the default modelbinding.
I am using `DataAnotations` for my objects and I want to apply my custom model binder for Enums only.
How can I achieve the custom Model binder along with default model binding.
In the custom Model Binder, I have the code as following.

---

```
 public bool BindModel(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var json = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                var jsonObject = (JObject) Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                var jsonPropertyNames = jsonObject.Properties().Select(p => p.Name).ToList();

                var requiredProperties = bindingContext.ModelType.GetProperties().Where(p =>p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute),
                                                                                           false).Any()).ToList();

                var missingProperties = requiredProperties.Where(bindingProperty => !jsonPropertyNames.Contains(bindingProperty.Name)).ToList();

                if (missingProperties.Count > 0)
                {

                    missingProperties.ForEach(
                        prop =>
                            {
                                if (prop.PropertyType.IsEnum)
                                    actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(prop.Name, prop.Name + " is Required");

                            });
                }

                var nullProperties = requiredProperties.Except(missingProperties).ToList();

                if (nullProperties.Count > 0)
                {
                    nullProperties.ForEach(p =>
                        {
                            var jsonvalue = JObject.Parse(json);
                            var value = (JValue)jsonvalue[p.Name];
                            if (value.Value == null)
                            {
                                actionContext.ModelState.AddModelError(p.Name, p.Name + " is Required");
                            }

                        });
                }

            }
            // Now we can try to eval the object's properties using reflection.
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: So, you want your model binder to act upon `Enums`, and use the default model binder for all other types?

Comment: Yes exactly.Can I acheive that functionality with custom binders?

Comment: I haven't used them for Enums, but are you not able to register the custom binder for the Enum type in your global.asax? The default model binder will apply for all other types that haven't been explicitly registered.

Comment: I am not bale to find the option for registerting to enums in global.asax.cs.