# Does Web API validation provider have anything for Enum properties?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, data-annotations

I am using `DataAnnotations` for DTO objects.
I am applying the `[Required]` attribute on DTO objects.
It is not working for the `Enum` type properties.
Is there way to customize Web API validation providers to handle this, or is there any other way I can validate `Enum` properties?

I have tried a custom model binder, but it does not give me the desired result.

For reference please see [Acheive Default model Binding working with custom model binder in WebPI and asp.net mVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048846/acheive-default-model-binding-working-with-custom-model-binder-in-webpi-and-asp)
.

Answer (score 3):

I 'may' have had the same problem.

I had the following code for a DTO that i wanted Web API to deserialize

```
public class FooDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public FooEnum FooEnum { get; set; }
        //.. other attributes omitted
    }
}

public enum FooEnum
{
    Foo, Bar
}
```

When i omitted the `FooEnum` from the `POST JSON data` in my request, it would always create a `FooDTO` with the first `FooEnum`. I think what happens is that its per default not a nullable value, and therefor it defaults to a value from the `Enum`.

I solved this by adding `?` to the end of the `Enum` attribute like so:

```
public class FooDTO
    {
        [Required]
        public FooEnum? FooEnum { get; set; }
        //.. other attributes omitted
    }
}
```

After this, if the `Enum` is omitted from the request body, the `[Required]` would invalidate the model state and i would get my expected result: The request would fail.